# Java: thread safe id generator (synchronization issue)

Tags: java

Let's suppose I have a very simple id generator class which can be use my many threads simultaneously. Will the following code work fine - I mean it will always return unique ids?

```
class Generator{
private int counter=0;

public int getId(){
 return counter++;//the key point is here
}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. It's not thread safe at all, you would need to `synchronize` your `getId()` method.

However it's better to use `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()` instead.

```
public class Generator {
   private final static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

   public static int getId() {
      return counter.incrementAndGet();
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is not safe?

Comment: Well, the variable isn't declared volatile and there's no synchronization, so threads won't see the changes made by other threads. In addition to that, `counter++` is a compound operation, so volatile by itself won't be enough. You'd need to synchronize the method, but `AtomicInteger` does a better, faster and simpler job.

Comment: So with using AtomicInteger the right class: class Generator{ private AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(); public int getId(){return atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();}? Could you provide the full code in your answer?

Comment: You might want to touch on the problem with integer overflow to answer the "will it always return unique ids?" part of the question.

Comment: @KErlandsson Well, considering that he was asking about a "very simple id generator" and isn't familiar with synchronization, he should be fine with 2 billion unique ids. After all, it's not even a persistent counter.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Generator{
    private static int counter=0;

    public static synchronized int getId(){
        return counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: static methods cannot refer non-static variables. You will get compile time error as `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field counter`